# What is the tiny dot of light in front of both lens in the image? I noticed it while trying to pass a 800 nm pulsed laser through the lens setup

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser

[image]The tiny white dots were formed in front of both the lens when I was trying to pass a 7W, 90 fs, 800 nm pulsed laser through the lens setup shown in the image.

I noticed that the dots disappear when I block the incident laser and only appear when lasing. As additional information the laser is propagating from left to right in the image.

Was curious if it was due to reflections.

Comment: I suggest adding arrows on your picture to point out the features you mean

Comment: Could it be that you are observing these dots at the foci of the lenses? In that case it could be that your laser intensity at the foci are high enough to produce voltage breakthrough in the air.

Comment: What color are these dots? Simply white as depicted in the image? If it's really air breakdown, I'd expect some violetness as is typical for sparks or corona discharges in air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflected light from the lenses are being focused causing either dust particles or air to breakdown.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I would have never imagined that the reflected light from the lens would be intense enough to cause an optical breakdown. I was curious as to why the reflected light doesn't cause a spot to burn on the card I used to align the laser. Also, I read that optical breakdowns are usually violent events that are accompanied by sudden bursts contrary to my observations prior to this question. I was hoping if you could shed some light on this aspect or correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: It’s the high peak power from the short pulse.  One of the surfaces of the lenses much be concave and causing a focus.  My guess is it’s not air breakdown but dust particles